# javascript and C# server communication

Tags: c#, javascript, sockets, websocket

i have developed an application in C#(client-server) using sockets for communication between client and the server. Now i want to create the same application for android using javascript (based on [development guide about javascript](https://developer.android.com/index.html)) but to keep the server made in C#(i can change the part with communication but not much). here is how the code looks:

server side:

```
connection.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade:  WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: " + aux));
connection.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n"));
```

where aux is:

```
public static String ComputeWebSocketHandshakeSecurityHash09(String secWebSocketKey)
    {
        const String MagicKEY = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        String secWebSocketAccept = String.Empty;

        // 1. Combine the request Sec-WebSocket-Key with magic key.
        String ret = secWebSocketKey + MagicKEY;

        Console.WriteLine("-   " + ret + "   -");

        // 2. Compute the SHA1 hash
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] sha1Hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ret));

        // 3. Base64 encode the hash
        secWebSocketAccept = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Hash);

        return secWebSocketAccept;
    }
```

I created a client in javascript with websockets that connects to a c sharp server. The problem is that after the handshake my connection closes and I don't know why. The only error I get is: "Unrecognized frame opcode: 7". I use Google Chrome 16.0.912.75.

Step by step:

1. WebSocket available
2. server receives the handshake request
3. Sec-WebSocket-Accept is generated and sent to the browser
4. the browser recognizes the key and the .onopen method is executed
5. after this I get the error

   ```
   var ws;
   $(document).ready(function () {

   // test if the browser supports web sockets
   if ("WebSocket" in window) {
       debug("Browser supports web sockets!", 'success');
       connect($('#host').val());
       $('#console_send').removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
       debug("Browser does not support web sockets", 'error');
   };

   // function to send data on the web socket
   function ws_send(str) {
       try {
           ws.send(str);
       } catch (err) {
           debug(err, 'error');
       }
   }

   // connect to the specified host
   function connect(host) {

       debug("Connecting to " + host + " ...");
       try {
           ws = new WebSocket(host); // create the web socket
       } catch (err) {
           debug(err, 'error');
       }
       $('#host_connect').attr('disabled', true); // disable the 'reconnect' button

       ws.onopen = function () {
           debug("connected... ", 'success'); // we are in! Big Grin | :-D 
       };

       ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
           debug(evt.data, 'response'); // we got some data - show it omg!!
       };

       ws.onclose = function () {
           debug("Socket closed!", 'error'); // the socket was closed (this could be an error or simply that there is no server)
           $('#host_connect').attr('disabled', false); // re-enable the 'reconnect button
       };
   };

   // function to display stuff, the second parameter is the class of the <p> (used for styling)
   function debug(msg, type) {
       $("#console").append('<p class="' + (type || '') + '">' + msg + '</p>');
   };

   // the user clicked to 'reconnect' button
   $('#host_connect').click(function () {
       debug("\n");
       connect($('#host').val());
   });

   // the user clicked the send button
   $('#console_send').click(function () {
       ws_send($('#console_input').val());
   });

   $('#console_input').keyup(function (e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) // enter is pressed
           ws_send($('#console_input').val());
   });

   });
   ```

If you need more information please reply. I am searching google for like 4h now on this opcode: 7 issue.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR for this.  It makes real-time apps with javascript much more manageable.

Comment: I presume the "Unrecognised frame" error is in the client (browser)? If so, is it possible your server is sending data after the successful handshake you posted code for above?  Running wireshark would allow you to see if there is any communication after the handshake.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) which is an open source .NET WebSocket server. Having a look at the code there should help you resolve your problem.